# Blank page on vercel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel, newsapi

My react app running well on localhost but after deploy on vercel it shows blank white page.

It show these error on console :-

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 ()"

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

I tried to correct length property of Infinite scroll package which I included in this app.